# vba ShellExecute print image without print dialog

Tags: vba, winapi

I am using `ShellExecute` to print my image.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
As Long

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)

    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

End Sub

Sub PrintImg()
    PrintFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.png"
End Sub
```

But, it will open dialog like below

[image]

Is there any way to print image without this dialog?

I know I could work around this by change the default program to open image with paint. But, it is not reasonable to change on every end-user computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is inevitable if you rely on a file association. It's out of your control. Think about what ShellExecute actually does. If you want control you will need to take control and incorporate code to perform the printing from your program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is a vba code from Excel, I am printing file with ShellExecute, what do you mean by `from your program`?

Comment: I mean exactly that. You are currently asking another program to do the printing. And it decided to show that dialog. If you want control do the printing yourself in your program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just want to print image from vba code, is there any solution? I am not sure what you mean by printing yourself.

Comment: Yes there is a solution. You write code to talk to the printer via GDI like any other Windows program does. I suspect that a large part of your problem is that you don't know what ShellExecute really does.

Comment: To be honesty, I am not familair with `ShellExecute`. A demo to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: A demo of what?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan use GDI to print the file without any dialog.

Comment: That's a huge job. Nobody is going to write the code for you. Start by learning how to print images using a language like C++ or Delphi which is easier to interface with Win32 and GDI. Then translate into VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (since you rely on an external application which simply sees "print" as the verb, what it will do is up to that application), but printing in Windows is like writing to a device context.

The approach of changing the default handler is also quite wrong, for you can never be sure what a third party application will do in the future unless it has a documented behaviour (usually, using a 3rd party application requires some well-documented automation which Paint does not have).

You can start at [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing) to take a look, and MS example in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-sending-gdi-output-to-a-printer-use) is a quicker example using GDI+. [Here](https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/printing-graphics-in-gdi-using-vb.net) is a Visual Basic sample.

Comment: My code is from Excel vba. How can I use `GDI+` from my vba code?

Comment: Example here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c39712f-fb49-4ef6-9fd2-245b79bb6c67/using-gdi-in-excel-vba?forum=isvvba